# Is there a difference between an expatriate and an immigrant?

Tags: immigration, terminology

Are the words expatriate and immigrant synonymous to each other? If not, where lies the distinction between the two?

Comment: I'd like to add the term *migrant worker* to this list.

Comment: See also [this ELL question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/300/55)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the definitions of words, and easily answered by any dictionary.

Comment: Also [this english.se question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97835/difference-in-usage-between-expat-and-emigrant).

Answer (score 3):

Immigration is usually permanent, or at least for an undetermined time.  An expatriate may be temporary.

I'd consider that:

- A *migrant worker* is anyone who is living and working abroad, usually temporarily, often from a poor country working in a richer country.  The move is often economically motivated.
- An *expatriate* is [more or less the same as a migrant worker](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/334/55), but may include pensioners living abroad, and has a different socio-economic context, as it's often used to describe people from rich countries living and working in either poor or rich countries.  The move may or may not be economically motivated.
- An *immigrant* is anyone who moved to another country permanently or for an indeterminate amount of time.  This includes a subset of migrant workers and a subset of expats.